# Servidor Socket Multi Thread e seus Clients conversando entre si

Tags: java, c#, servidor, socket

Estou com uma dúvida que está me matando e gostaria de compartilhar com vocês, talvez alguém tenha a resposta ou um caminho a seguir pra sanar essa dúvida.

Tenho uma boa experiência com desenvolvimento Web/Desktop, conexões API/REST e Socket. Mas todas estas conexões mesmo que em um server multi thread (independente da linguagem de programação) sempre trabalhei com o client conectando ao server, requisitando ou enviando algo, o server respondendo e se não mais for necessário é encerrado a conexão. Acontece que andei dando uma olhada em games online (**MMO RPG**) e ficou a minha dúvida, como um cliente conectado ao server consegue ver o outro cliente, interagir, etc...

Imagino manter uma lista de todos os clientes conectados no server cada um com o seu identificador, até ai tudo bem, mas como explicar que eu posso ver cada um conectado fazendo uma coisa diferente? Quer dizer que a cada segundo por assim dizer eu como cliente recebo do server a lista de clientes ativos e todos os status de todos naquele momento? Na minha cabeça isso parece um tanto pesado se pensando em muitos usuários.

Por tanto a minha dúvida, como eu enquanto cliente conectado ao servidor vejo os outros clientes e interajo com eles?

Imagine que você está jogando um jogo online e de repente aparece um novo jogador e anda, corre, ataca, pula, rola tudo isso vc está vendo, dai chega outro, e outro, será que eu recebo um pacotão de dados me falando de cada user conectado e o que eles estão fazendo ou estou pensando de mais sobre o problema e a coisa é mais simples?

De já agradeço as respostas e tempo de cada um :)

Comment: Stefano, acredito que o video no link a seguir pode ajudá-lo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xJyHERZ_D0

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário João, mas o vídeo que me mandou é exatamente o que eu estou acostumado a fazer, minha duvida está mais relacionada ao comportamento dos clientes, digo: imagine que 10 estão conversando ao mesmo tempo, você como o cliente 1 recebe a todo instante a situação dos outros 9?

Answer (score 3):

Bom,você deve pensar a nível de protocolo de comunicação e de que dados precisa realmente exibir na tela e em que momento vai receber dados e isso varia do tipo de jogo.

Exemplo, num jogo tipo LOL você não precisa circular os nomes dos jogadores pela rede durante toda a partida. Só no inicio, ao final, eles são descartados da memória do cliente depois do jogo.

Já num Tibia da vida, você precisa circular esses dados porque não tem uma fase onde você pode carregar esses dados, eles vão ser exibidos durante a movimentação, então, a sacada provavelmente está em focar no protocolo de comunicação, compactar os dados durante a transmissão, enviar somente ao mudar de mapa ou interagir, ou seja, analisa cada necessidade de envio de dados. Sem falar, que separar os players por servidor/região é uma pratica comum por conta da latência.

De uma forma geral, o primeiro passo é analisar o que pode ser colocado no cliente e o que deve vir do servidor.

1- Nunca, mas, nunca faça um cliente se comunicar diretamente com outro sem que o usuário tenha conhecimento e concorde com isso. Essa é uma questão simples de design para a parte de segurança, se você projetar assim, um cliente terá conhecimento do endereço de rede de outro e 'escutando' a conexão pode ter acesso a máquina do outro usuário. Outro problema latente com esse tipo de design é que a latencia entre diferentes players prejudicar mais de um jogador, pois o server não tem como gerenciar conexões diretas que não passam por ele e acabaria esperando demais em algum momento, inclusive, aumentando a complexidade do codigo pra controlar essas coisas.

2 - Separe a informação visual das mensagens que compõem o protocolo de comunicação do game. Uma coisa é o que você ve na tela, outra é o que circula na rede entre o servidor e o cliente, na maioria das vezes é por isso que os clientes são grandinhos para download. Um exemplo, o nome de um monstro não precisa circular na rede, basta o numero (ID) do monstro que é transformado localmente na imagem e no texto na tela.

3 - Todo conteúdo que pode ser exibido de forma padrão entre os clientes de uma sessão deve ser colocado no download do cliente para instalação. Somente dados de controle (identificadores de objeto) devem circular pela rede. Basicamente o fluxo entre o clique de um usuário e uma ação é envia clique ao server, server processa, devolve resposta ao cliente. Esse fluxo, obviamente, deve ser apenas no sentido de que animações e posicionamento executar, nunca dos dados de execução em si.

4 - Quase que por ultimo e resumindo, o server mantem o status real de todos os objetos, mapas e interações, realiza os processamentos e determina os resultados, já o cliente é apenas uma janela grafica que renderiza e exibe o resultado das ações, seja qual for o tipo de game.

5 - Projete o protocolo para tipos diferentes de mensagens, tipo, algum tipo de mensagem pode ser descartada se se perder na rede? Se sim, UPD, caso contrário, TCP.

Um exemplo disso é o momento em que vc tem lag e a tela quando volta já aparece numa posição totalmente nova (provavelmente morto) :D

Bom, não tem uma receita mágica e programar protocolos e jogos não é tão trivial.

Edit: Algumas pessoas andaram 'estudando'o protocolo do LOL, você pode encontrar esses exemplos no google (ex: um link em inglês :https://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2014/08/07/league-of-legends-game-protocol/)

Edit 2: Um link interessante com os numeros dos caras e um pouco da infra deles (tambem inglês: http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/10/13/how-league-of-legends-scaled-chat-to-70-million-players-it-t.html)